# Can't optimize Google Page Speed score for mobile without reducing speed on desktop

Tags: wordpress, mobile, pagespeed, elementor

I've created a website with Elementor and while I'm aware that Elementor have an impact on the loading speed, I'm confused about something.

When running the site through Page Speed Insights I'm getting pretty good results on desktop. The score on desktop is around 86, which I think is okay for now. On mobile however, the score is only 39. I've tried to use some cache plugins to eliminate som resources, and by doing that the score increased to about 49 on mobile. But at the same time the score on desktop drops dramatically when optimizing the mobile score.

[This photo shows an example of a thing I can fix to improve the speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNEYE.png)

Optimizing for mobile is not easy, especially since I have limited (non) coding skills.

Do any of you have any insights?

Answer (score 0):

The details you have provided make it impossible to answer your question.

However, in the image you shared it shows that loading Google fonts is possibly slowing you down a little bit. What part of your website is using Google fonts? Can you replace them with system fonts? (https://web.mit.edu/jmorzins/www/fonts.html)

Have you already covered the basics? https://mobile1st.com/7-ways-to-improve-mobile-page-speed/